# How to create an unblockable popup/popunder window or iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow, x-frame-options

I want to automatically open website B after website A is loaded. There seem 2 options.

One is using iframe to include website B on A's website. Unfortunately, B excerts a X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN policy thus cannot be iframed.

The other option is to open a new popup/popunder window to display B.  However, browsers block these popup/popunder windows.

I tried all the code found on the Internet that claim to bypass the X-Frame-Options restriction or create an unblockable popup/popunder window, but none works. The closest to success method is when a visitor moves his mouse pointer on the browser, the popup/popunder window displays(not blocked). I do not know how it is implemented.

I would like to know if a working solution exists at present.

Thanks!

Comment: X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN exists to disallow exactly this. If you can circumvent it, you shouldn't as the owners of Website B have expressed that they don't want to display their site with someone elses. That's what X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN means. 

You could maybe contact the owners of Website B and discuss with them the posibility of changing the header, but I would imagine that that's an unlikely outcome.

Comment: Potentially, if Website B is a simple static site, you could host your own mirror of it, without the X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: @James Is this what https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass actually does? Unfortunately, this web component does not seem to work now.

Comment: I saw lot of junk sites that seem to do this kind of work well. You know, when you open their webpage, it pops up lots of windows without being blocked. Do not know how they do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN exists for this exact purpose. You can ask the website owner to change the header to allow it.